# how to create an image loading animation in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, image, events, fabricjs

im loading images into my Fabric.js canvas using Image.fromURL like so:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function(img) {
    //blah blah blah
    canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
});
```

it works, but some images take a few seconds to load and the user has to sit there with no feedback.  i want to put in a loading animation but i cant find any events i can use to tell me when the image is finished loading and ready to display.

anyone have a solution?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```js
function createCanvasImage(callback) {
    // Placeholder-Code to set the loading-image spinning
        
    // Now load the image with AJAX
    var sauce = "http://..."
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: sauce,
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "HEAD",
        cache: true,
    });
        
    // If AJAX loaded your image, the browser will have it in cache,
    // so now we can add it
    request.done(function () {
        fabric.Image.fromURL(sauce, function(img) {
            // blah blah blah
            canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img);
        });
        
        // Placeholder-Code to stop the loading-image
        callback();
    });
}
    
createCanvasImage(alert.bind(undefined, "Image loading done!"));
```